# How to get second table values by first table values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Have data like :

```
declare @test_names TABLE(id int identity(1,1), name character varying(50),age int);
INSERT INTO @test_names(name,age) values ('name1',10),('name2',20);

declare @test_names_details TABLE(id int identity(1,1), test_names_id int,col1 int,col2 int,col3 int);

INSERT INTO @test_names_details(test_names_id,col1,col2,col3)
VALUES(1,2,3,4),(1,5,6,7),(1,8,9,10),(2,20,21,22),(2,23,24,25);
```

Want select details from second table for first table values. How to do it ? Output must be like :

```
field1     field2   field3
name1        10      
2            3       4
5            6       7
8            9       10
name2        20
20           21      22
23           24      25
```

**Edited**

In table I have many rows (name1,name2,name3..) for example I just write two of them

Comment: The output that you want can not be achieved using Joins and Group By. Try using loops.

Comment: @Luftwaffe can you give some example ? I have no idea how to do it. I also edited question. It is not necessary how we do it

Comment: Do you want the output in the same format as above?

Comment: @Luftwaffe after I will concate this string. Now i just need results like in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @output TABLE(field1 VARCHAR(50), field2 VARCHAR(50), field3 VARCHAR(50))
DECLARE @test_names_count INT,
        @counter INT
SELECT @test_names_count = COUNT(1) FROM @test_names
SET @counter = 1

WHILE (@counter <= @test_names_count)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @output SELECT name, age, '' FROM @test_names WHERE id = @counter
    INSERT INTO @output SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM @test_names_details WHERE test_names_id = @counter

    SET @counter = @counter + 1
END

SELECT * FROM @output
```

Answer (score 0):

**updated for any number of name columns:**

Set Based solution,replace column names with names of your choice

```
;with sortorder
 as(
 select name,age,min(col1)-1 as mincol
from  @test_names t
join
@test_names_details t1
on t.id=t1.test_names_id
group by name,age
)
 select * from sortorder
 union all
 select cast(col1 as varchar(5)),cast(col2 as varchar(5)),cast(col3 as varchar(5)) from @test_names_details
 order by mincol
```

Comment: I have in table many rows (name1,name2,name3 ...) and cant write in order by all of them

Comment: Can you give me example how it will be for more rows ?